# How to store images on android phone without showing them in gallery?

Tags: android, image

In my android app, I download images from a database. Each image has a primary key associated with it in the database. The way I store the images, is I make a folder for the app. Then a sub folder for each primary key to put the picture in. The problem with this is that there could be tons of images, and if I ever go to the gallery app to browse images, I see all these subfolders there. I don't want to see them all there.

I think a way to fix this is to keep all images in the same folder, and prefix them with their id or something, but I don't like this, as 1 id might have several pics associated with it.

Does anyone know of a better way to fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either store the images in a folder with a "." preceding the name like ".folder name" or create a file named ".nomedia" and place it IN the folder you store your images. Then anything you put in that folder will not appear in the gallery.